# Rails 5.0.4 No route matches {:action=>"update_status", :controller=>"tasks"}

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got the followed code:

tasks_controller.rb

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController
 before_action :set_task, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

 def index
 end

 def show
 end

 def new
  @task = Task.new
 end

 def edit
 end

 def create
  @task = Task.new(task_params)
end

 def update
 end

 def destroy
  @task.destroy
 end

 def update_status
  @task = Task.find(params[:id])
  @task.status = "Progres"
  format.js
end 

private
def set_task
  @task = Task.find(params[:id])
end

def task_params
  params.require(:task).permit(:title, :content, :datetime, :status)
end
end
```

_task.html.erb:

```
<%= form_tag({:action=>'update_status', :controller=>'tasks'},:method=>:post,:id=>"update_status",:name=>'taskstatus_form',:remote=>true) do %>
    <div class="btn btn-info"><%= submit_tag 'Progres' %></div>
<%end%>
```

and the config/routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root "tasks#index"
  put '/tasks/update_status'  => 'tasks#index'

  resources :tasks
end
```

This error appears:

> No route matches {:action=>"update_status", :controller=>"tasks"}

See anyone the problem? Thanx for help

Comment: on routes.rb post '/tasks/update_status' => 'tasks#update_status'

Comment: Thanx it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because your are not routing correctly, both your routes go to `index`, none to `update_status`.

Change this:

```
put '/tasks/update_status'  => 'tasks#index'
```

to this:

```
post '/tasks/update_status'  => 'tasks#update_status'
```

Comment: thanx for the answer, how can i make it possible when /tasks/update_status fire it go to the index?

Comment: @Yakalent It depends how you make the request, for example, if you want just to redirect when `/tasks/update_status` is typed in the browser, then add a route with `get`, like this: `get '/tasks/update_status'  => 'tasks#index'`. But if it will be requested from a `form` using post, then do: `post '/tasks/update_status'  => 'tasks#index'`. What is the exact behavior you are looking for?

Comment: @Yakalent Or what you want is to redirect to `index` after the code in `update_status` has being executed?

Comment: Yes thats is what i want

Comment: @Yakalent You will need to do that using _javascript_ since your action is only responding to `js`, and the form that requests to `update_status` uses _ajax_ (i.e. `remote: true`). Or, remove `remote: true` in your `form` and replace `format.js` in your controller to `redirect_to :index`.